# Jboss web-platform not loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am new to jboss and i'm trying to follow this giude:

http://yatb.giacomodrago.com/en/post/7/tutorial-restful-web-service-ejb-hibernate-jpa-jboss.html

So i downloaded JBOSS 7.1.1 instead of the 7.1.0 version. shouldn't be the problem right ?

I added JBOSS_HOME to my system env. variables.

> current JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

I am using java 7 cause i've read that jboss doesnt support java 8 ?

### problem:

I cannot reach the web-platform on localhost:9990 or localhost:8080.

> 18:44:29,289 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4938ms - Started 131 of 208 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)

### console output:

```
    Calling "C:\...\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone
   .conf.bat"
   ===============================================================================

     JBoss Bootstrap Environment

     JBOSS_HOME: C:\...\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

     JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java

     JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
   2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.se
   rver.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
   ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.c
   onfig=standalone.xml

   ===============================================================================

   18:44:24,882 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
   18:44:25,710 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
   18:44:25,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
   18:44:27,726 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
   18:44:27,726 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
   18:44:27,742 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
   18:44:27,742 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
   18:44:27,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
   18:44:27,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26)
   JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
   18:44:27,773 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
   18:44:27,773 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) 
   JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
   18:44:27,789 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48)
   JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
   18:44:27,789 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBA
   S013101: Activating Security Subsystem
   18:44:27,789 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS0
   11800: Activating Naming Subsystem
   18:44:27,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
   18:44:27,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
   18:44:27,898 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
   18:44:27,898 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
   18:44:27,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
   18:44:28,039 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread1-10) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
   18:44:28,367 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC servicethread 1-14) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
   18:44:28,789 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
   18:44:28,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\...\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
   18:44:28,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100:Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
   18:44:28,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100:Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
   18:44:28,992 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-16) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990 at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:210) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
   Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
           at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:144) at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:54) at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServ
   er(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:38) at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:147) at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.create(ManagementHttpServer.java:145) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
           ... 5 more

   18:44:29,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) 
   JBAS014774: Service status report
   JBAS014777: Services which failed to start: 
   service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /1  27.0.0.1:9990
   18:44:29,289 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
   18:44:29,289 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4938ms - Started 131 of 208 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: What is running on 9990 ?

Comment: Normally nothing, i am running jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:shutdown to close all old jboss instances

Comment: Check it with tcpview

Comment: it was some Nvidia application, NvNetworkService.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of other programs that potentially use those ports. The command you execute is specific to jboss and unable to close foreign processes.

Use netstat or tcpview if you prefer a Gui. Both tell you what is blocking that port.